# Java String Index Out of Range: -45

Tags: java, exception, substring

I am trying to accept a file from user (via file browser in GUI) and read the files line by line. Basically my interest is to know what exactly is written between character position 60 and 80 because on the basis of that I reach some conclusion need to take some decision (Reading a rinex.o file to be in particular).
But I get the error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -45` 
in the line: `String typeField=line.substring(60,line.length());` and cannot move ahead.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
  void parseRinexOFile(File inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
       File obsFile= inputfile;
//       if (obsFile.exists()) //Code to test if the file exists.
//               System.out.println("Hello, I exist"+ obsFile.getPath());
       // Create File Stream, Stream Reader and Bufferreader
        streamObs = new FileInputStream(obsFile);
        inStreamObs = new InputStreamReader(streamObs);
        buffStreamObs = new BufferedReader(inStreamObs);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(obsFile));
        String line="";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String typeField=line.substring(60,line.length());
                    typeField=typeField.trim();
                    if (typeField.equals("RINEX VERSION / TYPE")) {//Check if the observation file identifier is missing else find the version of the file

                    if (!line.substring(20, 21).equals("O")) {

                            // Error if observation file identifier was not found
                            System.err.println("Observation file identifier is missing in file "
                                                            + obsFile.toString() + " header");
                             ver = 0;

                    } else if (line.substring(5, 7).equals("3.")){                                                  
                            ver = 3;                                                        
                    } else if (line.substring(5, 9).equals("2.12")){                                                        
                            ver = 212;                                                      
                    } else {                                                        
                            ver = 2;  
                            System.out.println(" Current version:"+ver);
                    }                                               
                }
                    //System.out.println(line);

                }
                in.close(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens because the input line is shorter than 60 characters. You need to check the line length before calling substring().

Answer (score 0):

Your string is less than 60 characters long, so you can't pass 60 as the first argument to `String.substring`. The correct solution depends on your requirements, but one possibility is `line.substring(Math.min(line.length(), 60), line.length())`.

Answer (score 0):

You got this Exception because your `line.length()` is lower than `60`, test the length of your string before you do it:

```
String typeField="";
if(line.length()>60){
  typeField=line.substring(60,line.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're out of the `String` limits...

```
//this line is throwing the exception...
String typeField=line.substring(60,line.length());
```

Check if the string contains to avoid exception in this way:

```
if (line.contains("RINEX VERSION / TYPE")) {//Check if the observation file identifier is missing else find the version of the file
```